# Show the following action preserves the set $X = \{(g_1,...,g_p) \in G^p \mid g_1g_2 \cdots g_p = e \}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, group-actions

**Definition:** $G^p = \{ (g_1, g_2, ... , g_p) \mid g_i \in G\ \text{for all }i \}$

- Where $G$ is a finite group with $\lvert G \rvert = n$ and $p \geq 2$ a prime, with $p \mid n$.
- Also, where we view the indices $i$ to be representatives of the congruence classes of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ i.e., $[i]_p \in \mathbb{Z}_p$

**Definition:** We define an action of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ on $G^p$ by: $$a \cdot (g_1,...,g_p) = (g_{a+1},...,g_{a+p})$$ For $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$

---

**Problem Statement**

> Show that the action above preserves the set $$X = \{(g_1,...,g_p) \in G^p \mid g_1g_2 \cdots g_p = e \}$$ Where $e \in G$ is the identity.

---

For this, to the best of my understanding, we want to show that $$\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}_p,\ g_1 \cdots g_p = e\ \text{iff}\ g_{a+1} \cdots g_{a+p} = e$$ My attempt below is incomplete and casual. As such I would appreciate some guidance in how to proceed for that which I don't have down as well as correction/formalization for that which I have written down. Thank you.

---

Assume first that $g_1 \cdots g_p = e$. Since the indices $i$ are elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, $[i]_p \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ then we know that $g_1 \cdots g_p$ contains one $g_i$ for each $i \in \{0,...,p-1 \}$ and adding an $a$ simply "shifts" the product element by $a (\text{mod p})$ so that every value is still accounted for. So that for all $i \in \{0,...,p-1 \}$ there exists an $(a + i) \in \{0,...,p-1 \}$ so that $g_i \to g_{a+i}$. Since multiplication in groups is associative it doesn't matter the order in which we multiply and we can deduce that $$e = g_1 \cdots g_p = g_{a+1} \cdots g_{a+p} = e$$

Next, we assume that $g_{a+1} \cdots g_{a+p} = e$. Since the indices $i$ are viewed as the representatives of the congruence classes of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ we know that for any index we have $0 \leq a + i \leq p$ thus we can make the association that for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ we have $$g_{a + k} = g_i$$ For all $i \in \{0,...,p-1 \}$. Thus if $g_{a+1} \cdots g_{a+p} = e$ then $g_1 \cdots g_p = e$. By associativity of multiplication.

---

So I know this is nowhere near correct or clean enough for a formal proof but I kind of wanted to outline my thought process as best I could in an informal proof. Essentially, my thoughts about this problem go back to leveraging the congruence mod $p$ of the indices to show that no matter how much you "shift" them up (by adding $a$) or down (by subtracting $a$) you will still get all elements of the product in the range $g_i\ \text{for}\ i \in {0,...,p-1}$ and then by associativity it doesn't matter if it's the case that the left most element is, say, $g_5$ instead of $g_1$ the product is still the same, namely, $e$. Is this the right train of thought? As well, any guidance on how to formalize this would be appreciated.

Comment: If you did an arbitrary permutation instead of just shifting, "every value is still accounted for" as you say. So just knowing that all the $g_1$ through $g_p$ are there is not enough to deduce that it is still the identity. In general you should look at your proof and see that it doesn't apply to something stronger that isn't actually true. In this case, the stronger $S_p$ invariance rather than just what you wanted as $Z_p$ invariance.

Comment: You might consider looking at a specific example to see what is going on. Try to prove that $$2\cdot \big\{(g_1,g_2,g_3)\in G^{3}:g_1g_2g_3=e\big\}=\big\{(g_1,g_2,g_3)\in G^3:g_1g_2g_3=e\big\}$$

Comment: @AHusain, I'm a little confused. What exactly do you mean by arbitrary permutation instead of just shifting? Would it not be the case that adding $a (\text{mod p})$ to the index would necessarily shift the index by $a (\text{mod p})$? Also, by $S_p$ invariance are you saying I should treat the product $g_1 \cdots g_p$ as a permutation $(1 \cdots p)$ and then show that the analogue of the action on that permutation $((a +1) (a+2) \cdots (a +p))$ leaves the permutation invariant?

Comment: By arbitrary permutation $S_p$ invariance, you are saying $e = g_1 \cdots g_p = g_{f(1)} \cdots g_{f(p)} = e$ where $f$ is any permutation of the indices rather than the particular permutation which sends each index $i \to i+a$ modulo $p$. Your reasoning says arbitrary permutations would work too, but they don't. That tells you there was a mistake, because you accidentally proved something too strong to be true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The group $\mathbb{Z}_p$ acts by *cyclic permutation*. It suffices to show that
$$
g_1 g_2 \cdots g_p = e
\implies 
g_2 \cdots g_p g_1 = e
$$
since every other cyclic permutation is a power of this one.

A direct calculation works:
\begin{align}
g_2 \cdots g_p g_1 
&= e \bigl( g_2 \cdots g_p g_1 \bigr) \\
&= g_1^{-1} g_1 \bigl( g_2 \cdots g_p g_1 \bigr) \\
&= g_1^{-1} \bigl( g_1 g_2 \cdots g_p \bigr) g_1 \\
&= g_1^{-1} e g_1 \\
&= g_1^{-1} g_1 \\
&= e 
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer @Sammy Black. I wanted to ask a quick follow up question, if you don't mind; since the problem statement says to show $$g_{a+1} \cdots g_{a+p} = e\ \text{if and only if}\ g_1 \cdots g_p = e$$ It seems like this calculation satisfies the statement "$g_{a+1} \cdots g_{a+p} = e\ \text{if}\ g_1 \cdots g_p = e$" since, as you say, the cyclic permutation $g_{a+1} \cdots g_{a+p} = e$ is simply the $a^{\text{th}}$ power of the one above. Now are you claiming this calculation satisfied the statement in the other direction as well? If so, I'm having some trouble seeing it.

Comment: Unless it's the case that for the other statement we would use the proof as above but to some negative power?

Comment: This comes down to the fact that the action on the indices is cyclic: the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in particular, where $-b \equiv p - b \pmod{p}$. So the converse implication is just another example of the forward implication with group elements relabeled: 
$$
(a+p) \cdot g_{a + i} = (-a) \cdot g_{a + i} = g_i
$$
for any $0 \leq i < p$.

Comment: Perhaps an example clarifies. Say $p = 5$ and $a=2$. Note that $3 = 5 - 2 \equiv -2 \pmod{5}$, so acting by $3$ is the inverse of acting by $2$. So we have the pair of equations
$$
2 \cdot ( g_1 g_2 g_3 g_4 g_5 ) = g_3 g_4 g_5 g_1 g_2
\implies
3 \cdot ( g_3 g_4 g_5 g_1 g_2 ) = g_1 g_2 g_3 g_4 g_5
$$
Think of rotating the dial on a combination lock with only $5$ numbers on its face. If you turn forward by $2$, you then have to turn forward by $3$ to return to the original position. This is the essence of cyclic indexing (equivalently, the defining relation in the cyclic group).

Comment: Thank you! That was very clarifying indeed. Most of the time I get so lost in the weeds with all the abstraction that I forget it's important to take a step back and look at a concrete example to help get a grasp over the material.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you're confusing associativity and commutativity. The fact that the operation is associative simply means that $$(g_1 g_2)g_3=g_1(g_2 g_3)$$ for any $g_1, g_2,g_3\in G$. On the other hand, you're repeatedly using that the result of the operation does not change if we rearrange the factors, which is commutativity (and does not hold if for example $G=S_3$).

If you want a hint on how to proceed, let's consider the case where $a=2$. As you observed, we want to prove that $$g_3 g_4 \cdots g_p g_1 g_2 = e \qquad (\star)$$ using the fact that $g_1 g_2 \cdots g_p=e$. If you look at the left hand side of $(\star)$, we would really like to have $g_1g_2$ before the other terms. How can we do this? Multiplying by $(g_1 g_2)^{-1} (g_1 g_2) =e$ we get $$(g_1 g_2)^{-1}  \underbrace{(g_1g_2)g_3 g_4 \cdots g_p}_{=e}\, g_1g_2 =(g_1 g_2)^{-1} (g_1 g_2) =e$$ as required. Can you see how to generalize this for any $a$?

Comment: Well, as you constructed, we could multiply by the product $(g_1 \cdots g_a)^{-1}(g_1 \cdots g_a)$ and then for whatever $a + (p-a) = p$ we could utilize associativity to focus in on the product starting with $g_1$ and ending with $g_{a + (p-a)}$ (since it's $e$ by assumption) then to the right of $e$ would be those elements with indices $(g_1 \cdots g_a)$ which by multiplication with $(g_1 \cdots g_a)^{-1}$ yield $e$ overall